# Should one prevent its Nginx upstream servers to be directly reachable?

Tags: nginx

Say you are serving example.com with Nginx and two upstream servers, www1.example.com and www2.example.com. What is the correct way to (not) expose your upstream servers ? Is it important to hide wwwX.example.com ?

Do you setup wwwX.example.com to redirect to example.com when not reached via (i.e. proxied by) example.com's Nginx ? Or do you use a rel="canonical" link ? Or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the thing people do is have two interfaces on their load balancer (in your case nginx), one of which is internet-facing and one of which is not.  Connect the latter interface to a network which contains your servers and is not accessible from the internet.

This is a fairly common use case for VLANs.

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out by firewall or nginx rules all other IPs except example.com ones.